# Permissions in Windows 7 java unrecognizable in batch

Tags: java, vba, windows-7, batch-file, excel

I wrote a program to make a graphical Timeline and it works through some VBA and Java through the shell, but after transfering it over to Windows 7 from Vista I cannot seem to find a place to save the files so that the java program can access them. Please Help me. **Where can I save the files such that I can have the java  program access them and not throw an exception and blow up the program?**
Update Now whenever I try to shell the java program I get a file not found exception runtime error 53 and it's on the shell call
[image: Error that appears after calling java out of batch out of vba out of excel]

Error that appears after calling java out of batch out of vba out of excel
Some reason it won't let me do this.

Comment: You might get a better response if you post a code sample and the full stack trace of the exception you are getting.

Comment: your screen grab looks like java is not in your PATH.

Comment: I manually "PATH"ed it trust me it's there and from both the jre and a sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targetting Windows Vista/7, you can **build an EXE from a JAR file** that has a certain **manifest** in it that makes the EXE require admin rights. This way, file I/O will always execute with the correct userrrights!